# Better performance WPF dialog in unmanaged c++ application

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, performance

I have an application written in native c++ (MFC). Some dialogs in this application are written in C# and WPF. when I start the dialog for the first time (cold start) - it takes a very long time, but another run is already fast (warm start). Is it possible to improve performance by loading the appropriate assemblies when the splash screen is viewing, but not when the dialog is started for the first time? If so, in what way?

Comment: The [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2007/10/10/improving-wpf-applications-startup-time.aspx) on the first answer of that question tells you all you need to know.

Comment: This advice works for managed applications. If aplication is mixed (c++ and c#), above approach doesn't work.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What aspects of the linked question/answer don't apply and why?  If you edit your question with these details then the question may be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

Process your managed assemblies with ngen.exe during the installation of your software.

[Native Image Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: This can help, but its only 1 of many options and probably not the one I'd investigate first.